# NetSuite - error closing return authorization using web services

Tags: web-services, netsuite

Within NetSuite when trying to close out Return Authorization line items i receive the following error message:

> INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION
>   "You do not have permissions to set a value for element item.quantityreceived due to one of the following reasons: 1) The field is read-only; 2) An associated feature is disabled; 3) The field is available either when a record is created or updated, but not in both cases."

Here is the code:

```
                        //Pull down the RA in order to work with the line items in question
                        RecordRef rec = new RecordRef();
                        rec.internalId = internalId;
                        rec.type = RecordType.returnAuthorization;
                        rec.typeSpecified = true;

                        ReadResponse response = _service.get(rec);

                        //create the object from the response record returned
                        ReturnAuthorization ra = (ReturnAuthorization)response.record;

                        //cancel the order by updating the qty of each item to zero.
                        WriteResponse res = null;
                        ReturnAuthorizationItem[] raItemList = ra.itemList.item;

                        for (int lineCounter = 0; lineCounter < raItemList.Length; lineCounter++)
                        {
                            //only if the qty received is zero are we closing out the item(setting qty to zero)
                            if (raItemList[lineCounter].quantityReceived == 0)
                            {
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantity = 0;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantitySpecified = true;
                            }
                        }

                        //create a new object and add all the changes in order to update the order lines
                        ReturnAuthorization updRa = new ReturnAuthorization();
                        updRa.internalId = internalId;

                        updRa.itemList = new ReturnAuthorizationItemList();
                        updRa.itemList.item = new ReturnAuthorizationItem[raItemList.Length];
                        updRa.itemList.item = raItemList;

                        res = _service.update(updRa);
```

I am trying to update the line quantity to zero, which in affect will close the Return Authorization if everything has been zeroed out.  Question is how do i correct this permissions issue in order to run this update.  I have tried setting other fields on this same call.  No matter which field i try and update i get the same error message.  This is running under an admin account and all permissions look fine as far as i can see.  In fact i am running this very same logic against the SaleOrder object to close out Sales Orders with no issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Billy

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly edit that line item field. That field is maintained by Netsuite and reflects Item Receipts received against the RA.

If you want to close the RA without receiving just set the line item column field "Closed" to true.

Comment: Setting the isClosed flag doesn't work for me either.  I get the same error message

Comment: Yeah sorry. You need to create a new ReturnAuthorizationItem and ReturnAuthorizationItemList. see next answer

Comment: i figured it out.  just had to get rid of the fields that are uneditable.  Thank you for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this a little closer here is the solution:

Replace the if statement in the loop with this:

```
                                //only if the qty received and returned are zero do we close out the item(setting qty to zero)
                            if (raItemList[lineCounter].quantityReceived == 0 && raItemList[lineCounter].quantityBilled == 0)
                            {

                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantity = 0;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantitySpecified = true;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].isClosed = true;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].isClosedSpecified = true;

                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantityReceivedSpecified = false;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantityBilledSpecified = false;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].costEstimateSpecified = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantityReceivedSpecified = false;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].quantityBilledSpecified = false;
                                raItemList[lineCounter].costEstimateSpecified = false;
                            }
```

I am guessing that the fields i had to specific as false are fields that cannot be edited, hence the need to disclude them from the update.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better sample. Note the comment re orderline

```
/Pull down the RA in order to work with the line items in question
RecordRef rec = new RecordRef();
rec.internalId = internalId;
rec.type = RecordType.returnAuthorization;
rec.typeSpecified = true;

ReadResponse response = _service.get(rec);

//create the object from the response record returned
ReturnAuthorization ra = (ReturnAuthorization)response.record;

//cancel the order by updating the qty of each item to zero.
WriteResponse res = null;
ReturnAuthorizationItem[] raItemList = ra.itemList.item;

ReturnAuthorization updRa = new ReturnAuthorization();
updRa.internalId = internalId;

updRa.itemList = new ReturnAuthorizationItemList();

ReturnAuthorizationItem[] updateItems = new ReturnAuthorizationItem[raItemList.Length];

for (int lineCounter = 0; lineCounter < raItemList.Length; lineCounter++)
{
    updateItems[lineCounter].line = raItemList[lineCounter].line; // you'll need to test this. Setting only the line should result in no changes to the RA line items that are not to be closed. use the &xml=T view before and after to make sure orderline (hidden) is still populated properly.
    //only if the qty received is zero are we closing out the item(setting qty to zero)
    if (raItemList[lineCounter].quantityReceived == 0)
    {
    updateItems[lineCounter].isClosed = true;
    // raItemList[lineCounter].quantitySpecified = true; // is quantitySpecified a field? it wasn't as of the 2012.2 endpoint
    }
}

//create a new object and add all the changes in order to update the order lines

updRa.itemList.item = updateItems;

res = _service.update(updRa);
```

Comment: i am on 2015.2 - yes quantitySpecified is a field.